# Any way to constrain a generic interface to the type that implements it?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, generic-constraints

```
public interface ICloneable<T>
{
    T Clone();
}

public Foo: ICloneable<Foo>
{
    public Foo Clone()
    { 
       //blah
    }
}
```

Is there any way to constrain `T` to the type that implements the interface? (`Foo` in this case). It would be nice to enforce anything implementing `ICloneable` to return an instance of itself, and not any random type it fancies.

Comment: When you implement `ICloneable<Foo>`, you have to return a `Foo` or a derived. Am i missing something here?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I believe the point is that `Foo` could just as easily `: ICloneable<Customer>`

Comment: No. What would be the point? Can you show me code that uses that interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, basically. You can't do that with generic constraints. Also, you can't stop them implementing the interface multiple times with different `T` (as long as those `T` satisfy any `where` constraints, none in this case).

There is no `where` constraint that allows restriction to the implementing type.

You kinda sorta *can* do it as a method parameter restriction, but it isn't really satisfactory:

```
public static T SuperClone<T>(this T original) where T : ICloneable<T> {...}
```

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I believe you are mistaken. See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is possible to use Code Contracts to express this. Normally this is checked at runtime but it's possible to get a compile-time warning (see the notes later):

It goes something like this:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(CloneableContract<>))]

public interface ICloneable<out T>
{
    T Clone();
}

[ContractClassFor(typeof(ICloneable<>))]

internal abstract class CloneableContract<T>: ICloneable<T>
{
    public T Clone()
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<object>() != null);
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<object>().GetType() == this.GetType());

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Then if you have the following class definitions:

```
public class GoodFoo: ICloneable<GoodFoo>
{
    public virtual GoodFoo Clone()
    { 
        var result = new GoodFoo();
        Contract.Assume(result.GetType() == this.GetType());
        return result;
    }
}

public class BadFoo: ICloneable<object>
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        return new object(); // warning : CodeContracts: ensures unproven: Contract.Result<object>().GetType() == this.GetType()
    }
}

public class AlsoBad: GoodFoo
{
    public override GoodFoo Clone()
    {
        return new GoodFoo(); // warning : CodeContracts: ensures unproven: Contract.Result<object>().GetType() == this.GetType()
    }
}
```

This will work OK at runtime:

```
var good = new GoodFoo();
good.Clone();
```

These will cause runtime Code Contract failures:

```
var bad = new BadFoo();
bad.Clone();

var alsoBad = new BadFoo();
alsoBad.Clone();
```

Note that you *can* get a compile time time warning.

If you do a full Code Contracts Static Checking compile, you *will* see warnings about "ensures unproven" for the implementations of `Clone()` for `class BadFoo` and `class AlsoBad`.

There is no warning for `GoodFoo.Clone()` because of the `Contract.Assume(result.GetType() == this.GetType());` in its implementation.

However, Code Contracts Static Checking is (in my opinion) still too slow for anything but occasional checking, but your mileage may vary...